# How to invalidate timer without setting variable

Tags: swift, timer, nstimer

I am using the Timer class to execute certain code every x seconds. When something happens in this code, I want to invalidate the timer, thus stopping the "loop".

I have managed to do this by doing the following:

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true, block: { timer in

    //when something happens
    timer.invalidate()

})
```

However, I don't use this timer anywhere else in my code, so Xcode gives me the warning:

> Initialization of immutable value 'timer' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it

Obviously, this doesn't stop my app from running, but I would like to get rid of the warning.

I know that just using:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true, block: { timer in
    //do stuff
})
```

will still work, but then I don't know how to invalidate the timer. Just calling `invalidate()` inside the closure doesn't work (long-shot I know, but I tried it anyway).

Generally when looking at `Timer` question on SO, people are using global timer variables, which makes it easy to invalidate. However, I don't want to do this since it isn't necessary because, again, I'm not using the timer object once it's finished.

I looked around, thinking that this would be a fairly common problem, but I couldn't find anything helpful. Can anyone shed any light on how I could effectively invalidate the timer without setting a variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to still call `timer.invalidate()` but here `timer` is reference to the block of the `Timer`.

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true, block: 
{ 
    timer in //This is object that you need to use

    //do stuff

    //when something happens
    timer.invalidate()
})
```

Comment: Ah, yeah I forgot about the block var. Now I understand why it's necessary ;)

Comment: I'll accept this answer, in ten minutes, once it lets me

Comment: @BenjaminLowry Welcome mate :)